# Как создать галерею со списком следующего вида?

Tags: android, java

В общем требуется создать галерею следующего вида:

[image: галерея]

В общем, стрелки (кнопки) прокручивают на одно изображение влево и право соответственно. После нажатия на какую-либо стрелку(кнопку) происходит смена изображения в центральном квадрате (выделено красным квадратом), а так же меняется изображение, которое находится ниже списка, т.е. отображается ниже то изображение, которое выделено в списке.

Прошу вашей помощи, т.к. не знаю откуда начать копать, подскажите плиз, как лучше сделать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный контрол [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) вам в помощь

Comment: @alvin прав. Стандартный контрол подходит. [Пример кастомизации](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/07/android-gallery-control.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Все оказалось проще чем я думал, большое спасибо!